# I set up a private repo, and then cloned it to my local computer, now everything is read only. How do I set it to be editable in git?

Tags: git

Pretty new to how private repos work.. I set up a new repository like I would any other project. I opened up `gitbash` and cloned the project into a local directory, and finally copied some local files into that directory and did an initial commit.

However, the problem started when I tried to edit some of the files. Upon trying to save some changes, I get a `file set to read only` type error. I've got a ton of files in the repo, is there a way to set them all to be editable?

Comment: This isn't an issue with git. Change the permissions of the files in the repo that you cloned.

Comment: What does "set up a new repository like I would any other project" mean? *How* exactly did you create the repository? (Are you using GitHub?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy fix would be to execute

```
chmod -R 770 *
```

at the root of your git repository. These kind of problems indicate, however, that file permissions are screwed up in other places. I recommend you to read something about file permissions in UNIX and fix whatever the actual cause of your problem is.

Comment: +1 However, the fact that OP mentions git bash is a pretty good indication that he's using Windows...

Comment: @JackManey I am indeed a windows user, thus have no idea what I'm doing!

Answer (score 1):

On Windows in you repo you could execute:

```
cacls . /t /e /g Everyone:f
```

To recursively grant full access to everyone. However git on windows is does come with a number of MSYS tools. So you can do a

```
chmod -R 770 *
```

but the windows command is preferable because chmod does not precisely map onto Access Control Lists.